# Location of libcrt sources in VS2017?

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-c++

they used to ship sources for the C runtime in previous versions of VS. Would someone perhaps know what would be the default location in VS2017? Do they still ship the code with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah.. found it in Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.12.25827\crt
I hope the refactored code is as beautiful as the path is long.